# "Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted" - What is wrong here

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to parse the numbers from an IP address which is entered by the user. I have written the following code to take the input IP address from the user and print each bytes of the address.

**CODE:**(Right now I am assuming that the user input is like "xx.xx.xx.xx")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){

    char ip[16];
    char buffer[6];
    int i=0;
    char temp;
    int len;
    char *ptr1;
    char *ptr2;
    char delim = '.';
    while((temp = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        ip[i++]=temp;
    }
    ip[i] = '\0';
    ptr2 = ip;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        ptr1 = strchr(ptr2,(int)delim);
        strcpy(buffer,ptr2);
        if(ptr1 != NULL){
            buffer[ptr1-ptr2] = '\0';
            ptr2=ptr1+1;
        }       
        printf("\nString:%s",buffer);
    }


    getchar();

}
```

The code runs fine but at the end of the running or debugging session it gives the error

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted.
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: You're not checking *anything* to ensure you're staying within the bounds of your stack buffers!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Right now I am assuming that the input is A.A.A.A where A<=255.

Comment: Run your code under a debugger, and verify every access to your buffers. Again, you can't post to SO with stack corruption and not expect to have your lack of bounds-checking pointed out, *hard*.

Comment: The most immediate cause of your overflow is `strcpy(buffer, ptr2);`. You can't fit `A.A.A.A` into 6 bytes.

Comment: I am working on Visual Studio 2010. I did check the variables at each step and I changed `ip[i] = 'NULL'` to `ip[i] = '\0'`(yes, that was a mistake). My input was `1.1.1.1` . Still the same error.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh! That was the mistake. Thanks man.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
strcpy(buffer,ptr2);
```

This line is responsible for error. Your `buffer` size is 6 but `ptr2` has more than 6 characters (e.g xx.xx.xx.xx = 12)  so it is overflowing it. Increase `buffer` size. It will solve your problem.

Also Add **Array bound checking** as suggested by @jonathon. This line `ip[i++]=temp;` may create problem for larger input.

Comment: Also, for the love of `$DEITY`, **add bounds checking**.

Answer (score 2):

So many problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){

    char ip[16];
    char buffer[6];
    int i=0;
    char temp;
    int len;
    char *ptr1;
    char *ptr2;
    char delim = '.';
    while((temp = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        ip[i++]=temp;            // What is preventing you from writing to ip[16+] ?
    }
    ip[i] = NULL;                // '\0' is the NUL terminator. NULL is a pointer.
    ptr2 = ip;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        ptr1 = strchr(ptr2,(int)delim);
        strcpy(buffer,ptr2);     // Again, you can easily overrun buffer here
        if(ptr1 != NULL){
            buffer[ptr1-ptr2] = '\0';
            ptr2=ptr1+1;
        }       
        printf("\nString:%s",buffer);
    }


    getchar();

}
```